# Should we localize URLs for default language or not?

Tags: seo, url, multilingual, language, localization

I have a website running in English and Japanese and the default language is Japanese.

What are the advantages of one over the other solution:

- Solution 1. When accessing `example.com`, you will see only Japanese. When accessing `example.com/en`, you will see only English.
- Solution 2. When you access `example.com`, it will redirect you to `example.com/ja`, where you will see only Japanese. English site is still `example.com/en`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it’s better to include the language code for the default language, too. Quoting the pros from [my answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38363403/1591669):

> - If you decide to change the default language, you don’t have to change your URLs.
> - Consistency.
> - It allows you to redirect from `/` based on the visitor’s language preference.
> - It’s a signal that your site is available in multiple languages.
> - It’s easier for users that [want to](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/53087/17023) change the language from the URL.
> - It allows users of external search engines to search for pages in the default language only (`site:example.com/en/`; where `site:example.com/` would find pages in all languages).

On the root page you could either provide links to both sites (similar to [what Wikipedia does](https://www.wikipedia.org/)), redirect according to the visitor’s language settings ([or based on IP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21655524/1591669)), or redirect to the default language.