# Which one is better: /en subfolder or just the URL itself?

Tags: seo, url, multilingual, language

I am trying to make a multi-language website with fully translated content. And the thing is I am not sure about the URL for the homepage.

So the structure I am planning to prepare right now is using just the URL (like `example.com/`) for the English version and `/de`, `/jp` or `/tr` subfolders for the other language versions.

Would that be useful or should I use `/en` subfolder for the English version? If so, what kind of the homepage would you suggest (for `example.com/`), just a page with language selector or IP-based redirecting?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate to [*Should we localize URLs for default language or not?*](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/98630/17633) (I would give exactly the same answer here)

Comment: "folders" is a Windows thing. Everywhere else we call them "directories". The internet is based on Unix.

Answer (score 1):

There is good guide by Google: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en

I like the setting:

**URLs:**

```
example.net/en/ as hreflang for "en" and "x-default"
example.net/en-GB/ as hreflang for "en-GB" 
...
```

**Redirection:**
There is a 301 redirect based on user IP, default to /en/ if some wants to visit example.net but the user can always overrule language settings (for example with a language drop down menu in the header).

**Hint:**
If a user visits example.net/en/ but his IP is from Germany ask via popup / overlay / whatever if he prefers the de-DE Version (save the choice in a cookie).

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question and all though some similar questions have been asked I think yours is slightly unique.

**First there are a few things you should seriously consider as you do not want to start making domain/directory changes.**

- Are the languages being translated by a native speaker, Google translate or a CMS internally?
- Are you aggressively targeting a specific language?
- Are you selling a product or is it an informational website?

Once those things are figured out, your choice becomes easier to make

---

**Subdomains** are great if you plan on branding under one main domain name.

For example, example.com, jp.example.com, it.example.com

---

**Top Level Domains** are great if you do in fact want to reach each language based on their country. These usually require separate sites, domain names, costs and not a good idea if you plan on using an app or software for translations.

For example, example.jp, example.it. These usually require separate sites, domain names, costs and not a good idea if you plan on using an app or software for translations.

---

**Directories** are a very good idea to use if you do have an easy method to translate , branding one domain name, easy to remember domain names and if a person forgets how to navigate to a specific language, they can easily find it by going to the main domain name and simple select a language version.

The costs are less than the other options, easier to maintain from one server location and  verbally sounds more natural than es.example.com. Personally, I never liked the whole idea of esDotEXAMPLEDot.com, as it reminds me of a cheap sounding free DNS name.

---

Also what people do not realize is the BIG brands still use the directory method.

For example,

http://www.apple.com/es/

http://www.ebay.es/

---

**In the end, look at all the factors involved and you will make the best decision based on what benefits you financially and time investment to create a good workflow and who is your target and their location.**

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**No sub-folder for default language.** Is default lang English, then no sub-folder.

I don't like when page force me (IP redir) to lang version form my country. I prefer to read things in English. I recommend classic lang selector (with country flags - I love flags, site looks so international :-).

Definitely use 'hreflang'.